# How to mock throw new customException?

Tags: junit, mockito, test-class

Hope all are doing good.

I am wanted to mock one of my exception which is inside one private method like below :

```
 private void verifyScenarios(String empid, String token) {
   if (Validation if true)  // Line 1 :
    throw new CustomException("my message"); //Line 2
   else
    any code.    
 }
```

Line 1: will be true.
Line 2 : This line throwing exception because of that my junit test case is failing, Is there any way to mock line 2 and make it success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such things are not possible with Mockito, however I believe that all you need is to assert (pass the test) if exception is thrown, because it is a part of your business logic.

Try `@Test(expected = CustomException.class)` instead of `@Test` if you are using JUnit 4. Test will pass only if code will throw your exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [expected exception rule](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html). With this solution you can easily check the error message that is thrown as well.